# How to sort data with group-adjecment in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to sort data descending order? In parentheses some year string is same but before year string some text e.g. `Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2017)` and  `Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (9th Cir 2017)`. We want change only before year same text then I am using `substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')`. If year is different then code is working fine e.g. `AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994)` and `AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996)`. If coming is same year then code not work. Please check last two entry's
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<p content-type="emLetHead">A</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">A.M. v Albertsons, LLC (2009) 178 CA4th 455:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ABBA Rubber Co. v Seaquist (1991) 235 CA3d 1:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2017) 2 C5th 1074:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (9th Cir 2017) 865 F3d 1261:</named-content></p>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:function name="mf:extract-year" as="xs:integer?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\(.*?([0-9]{4}).*\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 1]/xs:integer(.)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="let $year := mf:extract-year(.)
                    return if ($year) then -$year else 1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output**

```
<root>
   <p content-type="emLetHead">A</p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">A.M. v Albertsons, LLC (2009) 178 CA4th 455:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">ABBA Rubber Co. v Seaquist (1991) 235 CA3d 1:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1996) 13 C4th 1017:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">AFL-CIO v Unemployment Ins. Appeals Bd. (1994) 23 CA4th 51:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (9th Cir 2017) 865 F3d 1261:</named-content>
   </p>
   <p content-type="emCase">
      <named-content content-type="emEntry">Mendoza v Nordstrom, Inc. (2017) 2 C5th 1074:</named-content>
   </p>
</root>
```

**Code** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/20

Comment: If you want to sort by the year but the year is the same for two items then how is the sort order determined?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, If year is the same for two items then order sort by descending order e.g. (`(9th Cir 2017)`, `(8th Cir 2017)`, ..`(2017)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps extracting anything inside `()` and sorting as a string suffices:

```
<xsl:function name="mf:extract-sort" as="xs:string?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 1]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="let $sort := mf:extract-sort(.)
                    return if ($sort) then $sort else 1" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf

Or perhaps use several `xsl:sort` for the different parts in the desired order/priority:

```
<xsl:function name="mf:extract-year" as="xs:integer?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)([0-9]{4})\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 2]"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="mf:extract-sort" as="xs:string?">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence
        select="analyze-string($input, '\((.*?)\)')/*:match/*:group[@nr = 1]"/>
</xsl:function>


<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="substring-before(named-content[@content-type = 'emEntry'], '(')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="let $year := mf:extract-year(.)
                    return if ($year) then -$year else 1"/>
                <xsl:sort select="let $sort := mf:extract-sort(.)
                    return if ($sort) then $sort else 1" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/3

Comment: Sir, Now is working fine this condition If I have add one more entry different year (2018) then get output wrong descending order e.g. `(9th Cir 2017)`, `(2018)`, `(2017)` s/b `(2018)`, `(9th Cir 2017)`, `(2017)`. Please check (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/2).

Comment: @Sandy, perhaps it helps if you use more than one `xsl:sort` with different sort keys in the wanted priority/order. I am afraid as long as you don't define clearly what kind of pattern the content follows and which parts are to be used as sort keys I can give you some suggestions but you will need to apply them on your own until they satisfy your exact requirements.

Comment: Sir, If I am run this code full XML then showing a some error e.g. "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the result of call to mf:extract-year (1967, 1968)" (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/6). Please can you check and resolve this error?

Comment: Sir, Please help me. Show some  error and last two and three line s/b not moved. Here is small e.g. (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jf/7).

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense that you change requirements after accepting an answer and then expect anyone to resolve the new problem raised in some comments. Ask a new question.